# Why can't I use my VBA code after restarting Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have created a simple code in Outlook (ThisOutlookSession).

```
Sub test()

   MsgBox "test"

End Sub
```

when I close Outlook I get the following message asking me if I want to save the VBA Project:

[image]

I clicked Yes but when I reopen outlook the code doesn't work.

On this website http://www.outlookcode.com/threads.aspx?forumid=2&messageid=29598 I just found that I can delete the file *VBAProject.OTM* and recreate the code but it doesn't help me if I have to do it every time.

Is there any way to make sure my VBA code works every time I restart Outlook?

Comment: Yeah I create it in *ThisOutlookSession*. But somehow when I close and restart, the code is still saved in *ThisOutlookSession* it just doesn t run anymore

Comment: *When I close Excel* - yet that msgbox says "Microsoft Outlook". How are you adding the code to Outlook?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes sorry I meant Outlook not Excel. I updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "macros" are disabled. Once you enable them, this works pretty nicely on `Application_Startup`:

[image]

To enable the "macros", click the last radio button from the screenshot below in the Trust Center:

(File>Options>Trus Center>Trust Center Settings>Macro Settings>Enable All Macros)

[image]

- [Enable/Diasble Macros](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6)